# How to show and hide sublists in a recursive ng-template in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, recursive-templates

I looked up a lot of different answers here but most of them are not accurate.
So, I wanted to ask what a good approach would look like to show and hide lists (ul) but only the list which was clicked on via onclick.

I have the following tempplate

```
        <ul *ngIf="children">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context:{ $implicit: children }"></ng-container>
        </ul>
          
          <ng-template #recursiveListTmpl let-children>
          <li *ngFor="let item of children; let i=index">
              {{item.name}}
              <ul *ngIf="item.children" class="sublists">
                  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
              </ul>
          </li>
          </ng-template>
```

`Children` is an array of objects containing a name and further children.

I tried to bind specific classes for each sublist and then get those element via `document.getElementsByClassNames`but it did not work correctly.

Do you have any currently correct approach to tackle my problem? How should I try to toggle those sublists? I really have no idea anymore...
My Angular Version is 9.

Comment: you can add an extra property item.children.hide and toggle it by a click function and use it in <ul *ngIf="item.children && !item.children.hide" class="sublists">. Please share a screenshot of your list and sublist

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. The lists represents a directory so all ```<ul>``` sublists are directories  and all  ```<li>``` items represent the files of the directory and it works pretty well. I just have to add a toggle functionality for which I have no approach yet. I could add an extra property but if it is possible,  I would like to do it without an extra property.

Answer (score 1):

you can add hidden of type boolean in your list, by default it is false, when you want to show the sublist, change it to true

For example

```
          <li *ngFor="let item of children; let i=index">
              <div *ngIf="item.hidden">
                  {{item.name}}
                  <ul *ngIf="item.children" class="sublists">
                  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context:{ $implicit: item.children }"></ng-container>
                  </ul>
              </div>
              <button (click)="showHide(item)">Show/Hide</button>
          </li>
```

On click change it to true, makes it visible
For Example in yout .ts file

```
showHide(item) {
    item.hidden = !item.hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Would there be another approach without  extending the object by a property of type boolean?

Comment: you can use this approach in Link https://toolset.com/forums/topic/javascript-to-hideshow-div-in-view-loop-item-targeting-first-result-only/#post-578599  but this is not angular approach